# JSON data from Django to D3 graph

Tags: javascript, html, django, templates, d3.js

I'm attempting to edit a D3 bar graph http://bl.ocks.org/3885304 to fit JSON data from Django. I have a variable generated in Django which is JSON format: [{"score": 1, "color": "blue"}, {"score": 5, "color": "green"}, {"score": 3, "color": "red"} etc. So I want to the color on the x-axis and score on the y-axis.

What's a way to implement the Django variable into the HTML template without having to create a tsv or csv file?

Answer (score 2):

Getting data into the right format and ready to go is typically something you do in your model. Here is a trivial hypothetical example:

```
# In models.py:
class Address(models.Model):
    street = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def get_full_address(self):
        return self.street + "\n" + self.city + ", " + self.state
```

Now in your view, pass the model instance into the template:

```
return render(request, 'address.html', {'address': address_object})
```

And in the template:

```
{{ address.get_full_address }}
```

... will return the textually formatted address.

So, if I wanted to supply this to a JavaScript jQuery function (again, for hypothetical demonstration) I could say:

```
<span id="address_label"></span>
<script>
    ...
    $("#address_label").html("{{ address.get_full_address }}");
    ...
</script>
```

Comment: How do I implement the {% address.get_full_address %} into the above D3 html to simulate the bar graph? I'm interested in the integration of Django into that D3 html template.

Comment: I just need to add your part to the HTML without removing anything to get the graph to work? Sorry, I'm completely new to JavaScript.

Comment: Django's template engine is merely providing a string. That string can be used in any JavaScript function you wish. So, for example, you could create a function in your model called "my_tsv_format_helper_function" in order to present the data in TSV format. Then, in your template you can get that string using d3.tsv.parse({{ data.my_tsv_format_helper_function }}). You also have the option of getting the data through a URL & other data formats like CSV or JSON it seems. https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV#wiki-tsv_parse

Comment: Gotcha. I was hoping for a way to bypass creating a csv or tsv file. Is there a way to directly send the data to the d3 html? Otherwise I'll have to constantly write and read files.

Comment: you could fetch the data through a URL. there's never a point where a file is created, so i don't quite know what you mean. it's true that the data is written into the web page. the data is never contained in a single separate file, on a disk, with a filename.